# Why the google.maps.places.Autocomplete generated search address gives ZERO_RESULT while geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added below API link for google map:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?Place=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

On window load event map loads with default lat and long values specified hard coded in `loadShowMap()`. And also have register text box for `AutoComplete`.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadShowMap);

function loadShowMap() {
    var input = document.getElementById('txtSearch');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4925374, -99.9018);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    mapgoogle = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    NewMapLoad(mapgoogle, geocoder, '');

    $('#btnMapSearch').click(function () {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#txtSearch').val();
        deleteOverlays();
        if (address != '') {
            NewMapLoad(mapgoogle, geocoder, $('#txtSearch').val());
        }
        else { alert('Please enter a Location to Search'); }
    });
}
```

As per auto complete feature it providing the match address as in below screen:

[image]

Then I select "Marketfair Mall, Skibo Road, Fayetteville, NC, United States". Then on search button click below function gets called. Which sets initial marker and the one which we currently searching.

```
function NewMapLoad(Nmapgoogle, geocoder, searchplace) {
    var strAddr = "Hollywood, LA"
    var strPopupDiv = "<table cellPadding='0' cellSpacing='0' style='width:100%;'> <tr><td>" + "Initial Point" + "</td></tr></table> ";
    var strSearchDiv = "<table cellPadding='0' cellSpacing='0' style='width:100%;'> <tr><td>" + "Search Point" + "</td></tr></table> ";
    var PointColor = "RED";

    var OrglatLon = document.getElementById('hdnactlocation');
    var Orglat = "", OrgLon = "";

    if (OrglatLon != null && OrglatLon.value.split('|').length > 1) {
        Orglat = OrglatLon.value.split('|')[0];
        OrgLon = OrglatLon.value.split('|')[1];
    }
    else if (OrglatLon != null && OrglatLon.value.trim() != "") {
        strAddr = OrglatLon.value;
    }


    AddMappointsNew(Orglat, OrgLon, strPopupDiv, geocoder, mapgoogle, PointColor, strAddr, "Initial Point");

    if (searchplace != '' && searchplace.toLowerCase() != 'clone') {
        AddMappointsNew('', '', strSearchDiv, geocoder, mapgoogle, "GREEN", searchplace, "Search Point");
    }
    if (searchplace.toLowerCase() == 'clone') {
        AddMappointsNew(orglat, orglon, strSearchDiv, geocoder, mapgoogle, "GREEN", strAddr, "Search Point");
    }


    overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.draw = function () { };
    overlay.setMap(mapgoogle);
}
```

For that setting initial and searching marker over map below function gets called:

```
function AddMappointsNew(lat, lon, strpopup, geocoder, mapgoogle, pointcolor, address, title) {

    var point;
    var iconlnk = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png";

    if (pointcolor != "" && pointcolor == "GREEN") {
        iconlnk = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png";
    }

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();            
    var addressdiv = $('<div/>').html(strpopup).html();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                mapgoogle.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: mapgoogle,
                    icon: iconlnk,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: title
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: addressdiv,
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    maxHeight: 200
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(mapgoogle, marker);
                });
                if (pointcolor != "" && pointcolor == "GREEN") {
                    setSearchmarker(marker);
                }

                markersArray.push(marker);
            } else {
                mapgoogle.setZoom(5);
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

            }
        });
}
```

But only initial marker getting set over map and for the geocode address returned from auto complete feature gives an error "ZERO_RESULT".

Comment: Most likely because that is not an address, it is a place.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, with the posted code, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteOverlays is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [Places Autocomplete Example on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) you will see that you don't need to Geocode twice which is essentially what you are doing. You run the autocomplete which actually returns the Place and then you have a search button to then to a search on the address again.

I have put together a small sample of what you should try out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/bcw43rr2/)

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
    if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        mapgoogle.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        mapgoogle.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        mapgoogle.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapgoogle,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
    marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
            (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
            (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
            (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
    }

});
```

Comment: I not cleared with above can you suggest what should I have to do with my code?